# Domain Admin on Win 7 64-bit can not install programs

Tags: .net, windows-7, installation, permissions

The application is a .net application and need admin privilege to install. 
- If you log in as a local admin, the installation can be done.
- If you log in as a domain admin, running the package by right-click and selecting "run as administrator" will pop up a message box complaining that "admin privilege is needed to perform the installation."

Domain admin is a member of local administrators group. The Active Directory server is set up on a windows 2008 server by the default installation, nothing is changed after the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Try holding down ctrl/shift and then right click on the installer package, you will see an option called "run as different user".  Then enter in your user details and see if that works,  this might not be the answer to your question but it is a good trouble shooting step.

Comment: Further investigation, it shall have something to do with service. There's a windows service included in the MSI package. It works on a Win 7 32-bit OS with pop up message windows, if you click view the message, then you can insta